# Equivalent of django's runserver logs on apache

Tags: django, apache

In running django's runserver, the server requests show up on the cli, like so --

```
[18/Aug/2011 16:56:17] "GET /profile/ HTTP/1.1" 200 142406
[18/Aug/2011 16:56:19] "GET /talent/ HTTP/1.1" 200 229005
[18/Aug/2011 16:56:20] "GET /videos/ HTTP/1.1" 200 92793
```

If I have apache running, how would I get these same logs so I can see what's going on in real time on the server? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you'll be using cgi or fastcgi to run your django app within apache, those logs will appear automatically in apache's logs (by default, access_log for accesses, and error_log for errors).

So just setup a script to watch for your application - for example, something like:

```
tail -f /var/log/httpd/access_log | grep '/path/to/django/application'
```

would work.

Answer (score 0):

You can also change the location of the logs by explicitly stating it in your apache 
configuration file that pertains to the django instance by using the command ErrorLog and CustomLog (with the necessary flag)

```
<VirtualHost >
ErrorLog "logs/host.foo.com-error.log"
CustomLog "logs/host.foo.com-httpd-access.log" combined
#
# You Django Specific Settings
#
#
</VirtualHost>
```